# How to merge parameter?

Tags: parameters, palantir-foundry

I'm trying to merge parameters from contour analysis and from reports. but I can't  "Cannot merge - Incopatible parameter type". One is 'double' type, another one is 'string' type. and I can not change parameter type.

any tips and tricks?

Answer (score 0):

To merge a parameter in Foundry Reports the parameter types must match. Therefore, you need to update the parameter type either for your Contour analysis or report (and maybe other things in the report) so they're the same.

Given one is a double type and the other is a string type, it sounds like the parameter *probably* represents a floating point number and should be a double type.

You mention 'I can not change parameter type'. I'm not sure if this refers to the Report or Contour analysis or something else, but if you're unable to change it maybe have a look in the sharing panel to identify who is the owner of the Report/Contour analysis and ask them to change it. Alternatively, you could copy the Contour analysis (`File` > `Duplicate file`) into somewhere you have permission to edit and change the parameter type there.